# SaltStack: How to create user and a directory in his HOME directory?

Tags: saltstack

I want to create a user and a directory in his HOME directory.

Unfortunately the HOME directory is not allways directly under `/home`. On some minions it is under `/localhome` and some use `/users/`.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144324/how-to-i-retrieve-the-home-directory-of-a-user

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ~USER/ syntax:

```
fred:
  user.present

dir_in_home:
  file.directory:
    - name: ~fred/foo
```